# Scope a single input in Vue built from JSON

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a simple quiz with vuejs. I've been working in https://codepen.io/jasonflaherty/pen/NBaJLO on this. I am able to get the correct responses to the checked input, however, it is not scoped to this.input and cascades to all radio buttons. I tried to use bind class with:

```
<span class="" v-bind:class="{ 'badge badge-success' : isCorrect, 'badge badge-danger' : isWrong, 'showthis' : showIt }">{{response.correct}}</span>
```

and am currently using:

```
v-if="isCorrect"
v-if="isWrong"
```

However, it is the same issue with the scope bound to the same input vs all of them.

What am I missing in vue to make this distinction?

Comment: Please put your code here.  You can leave the codepen, but you need to also include your code here.

Comment: I'm always now sure how much to put. All of it or the main areas in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track at the question level rather than the global level.

Here are a couple simple changes you can make.  Notice the input changes for value and v-model and also the conditions for the correct/wrong spans.  This creates a property, `selection` on each question to track the currently selected answer for this specific question.

```
<li v-for="response in question.responses">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"
          :key="index"
          :name="question.group"
          :value="response.text"
          v-model="question.selection">
           {{response.text}} 
    <span v-if="question.selection === response.text && response.correct ==='Correct!' ">
      Correct
    </span>
    <span v-else-if="question.selection === response.text && response.correct !=='Correct!' ">
      Wrong
    </span>
  </label>
</li>
```

You could clean it up some more by altering your data model.  There is no reason to save the `correct` text in the data.  You can simply have the answer as a property and determine the textual response based on the `selection`.

```
var quizquestions = {
  questions: [
    {
      text: "Subtract 219 from 500.",
      group: "qone",
      responses: [281, 719, 218, -219],
      answer: 281, // correct answer
      selection: null, // for v-model to track selected
    },
  ]
};
```

Comment: Excellent. Welp, i've learned a lot about methods, computed, watch etc... and didn't need any of it... lol. V-MODEL is just become more than I first understood!